# Basic authentication for Silverlight browser

Tags: c#, security, silverlight, url

I'm unable to connect to this URL using `WebRequestCreator.BrowserHttp`, I am however able to connect using `WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp`. Here's a sample of the code I'm using,

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", WebRequestCreator.BrowserHttp);
var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("username:password");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```

I'm trying to avoid using the 'Windows Security' dialogue box and I cannot use `WebRequestCreator.BrowserHttp` for my project.

**Edit:**

When using `WebRequestCreator.BrowserHttp` I get

> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected
>   range

and nothing in fiddler. If I use `WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp` I get

```
Authorization: Basic
```

in Fiddler

Comment: I'm confused.  You cannot use BrowserHttp, which doesn't work anyway?  Why not just use ClientHttp?

Comment: @AriRoth I cannot use ClientHttp because the browser will buffer 0.25Mb before sending it to the client. I'm using this code for a live MJPEG video stream so I need to get each image right away.

Comment: Attach Fiddler and check the differences between both requests: http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: @user18044 When using WebRequestCreator.BrowserHttp I get  System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range and nothing in fiddler. If I use WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp I get Authorization: Basic in Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do both Basic and Bearer (JWT) Authentication on a current silverlight project.

```
/* 
* NOTE:
* It turns out that Silverlight provides HTTP handling in both the Browser and Client stack. 
* By default Silverlight uses the Browser for HTTP handling. 
* The only problem with this is that Browser HTTP Handling only supports GET and POST request methods.
*/
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("https://", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("username:password");
// Default headers will be sent with every request sent from this HttpClient instance.
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```